# Error creating application autoscaling target on AWS when using Terraform - Defining `scalable_resource` for custom `aws_appautoscaling_target`

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation, aws-auto-scaling

## Goal

I'm implementing an auto-scaling solution for Kinesis data streams.

One possible solution, which I am following, is well documented in the [aws-samples/aws-application-auto-scaling-kinesis](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-application-auto-scaling-kinesis) repo. However, the sample code utilises a [cloudformation](/questions/tagged/cloudformation) yaml template. I wish to define the same using [terraform](/questions/tagged/terraform).

## Story so far

When trying to create a scaling target for `my_custom_resource`,

```hcl
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "my_custom_resource" {
  resource_id        = "https://${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.my_api.id}.execute-api.${var.region}.amazonaws.com/prod/scalableTargetDimensions/${var.stream}"
  scalable_dimension = "custom-resource:ResourceType:Property"
  service_namespace  = "custom-resource"
}
```

All the attributes have been built by following the [AWS Auto-Scaling docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/APIReference/API_RegisterScalableTarget.html#API_RegisterScalableTarget_RequestSyntax)

The same resource is created using CloudFormation in the linked AWS repo:

```yaml
KinesisAutoScaling:
  Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
  DependsOn: LambdaScaler
  Properties:
    ResourceId: !Sub https://${MyApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/prod/scalableTargetDimensions/${MyKinesisStream}
    ScalableDimension: 'custom-resource:ResourceType:Property'
    ServiceNamespace: custom-resource
```

<sup><sup>Note: Irrelevant attributes omitted for brevity.</sup></sup>

## Problem

`terraform apply` produces the following error:

```
Error: Error creating application autoscaling target:  
ValidationException: Validation failed for resource:  
https://k5df89sd23.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/scalableTargetDimensions/my-test-stream,  
scalable dimension: custom-resource:ResourceType:Property.  
Reason: Scalable resource not found

  on application-autoscaling.tf line 9, in resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "my_custom_resource":  
   9: resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "my_custom_resource" {
```

---

## What might be wrong in the terraform definition?

---

I am aware that Terraform supports CloudFormation Templates using `aws_cloudformation_stack` - a workaround I genuinely wish to avoid.

Comment: @matt-schuchard - do you think there isn't a flaw in my resource definition? I'm quite new with terraform, so can't be certain.

Comment: Never mind; just double checked the documentation and your value for the `resource_id` is incorrect: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/appautoscaling_target.html#example-usage.

Comment: @MattSchuchard - On that page, if you scroll down to the attributes and follow the link mentioned in `resource_id`, that leads to AWS docs. There is a section for Custom Resources on there which is what I have followed to arrive at my `resource_id`. Is it still wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> DISCLAMER: I know the question has been asked a while ago, but I'm answering anyway just in case it might help someone else... It certainly would have helped me

---

Assuming you're trying to reproduce the content of the [link you put in the question](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-application-auto-scaling-kinesis), then here's what I think could be wrong:

### Certainly part of the answer : `aws_appautoscaling_target.my_custom_resource.resource_id`

If you have created an `aws_api_gateway_deployment` resource to reproduce the [MyApi](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-application-auto-scaling-kinesis/blob/9fe4d11dbfdce08e698a72267e74484779737894/cloudformation/custom-application-autoscaling-kinesis.yaml#L147) part of the **aws-sample**, then you're in luck!
you can use this :

```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "my_custom_resource" {
  # ...
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_deployment.gateway.invoke_url}/scalableTargetDimensions/${var.stream}"
  # ...
```

> If you want details on how to get this ^ working, see below...

But keep in mind that this might not be enough!

---

### Probably part of the solution too : the internal linking and permissions required for the creation of the `aws_appautoscaling_target`

> always assuming you're following the [same example](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-application-auto-scaling-kinesis) and that you've implemented *most* of *all* of it with `terraform`...

also

> DISCLAIMER: I'm not *certain* about the exact reason for the rest of this answer. I suspect that it has something to do with the requirements of the internal API of the AWS Auto Scaling service.

---

#### TL;DR: Everything needs to be connected and working before you can register the autoscaling target

This part :
[image: hint]
of the `README.md` of [this other project that covers the integration you're trying to achieve](https://github.com/aws/aws-auto-scaling-custom-resource)  hints at this.

#### Long version; What I had to fix in my implementation:

1. Lambda response format
2. API Gateway settings and wiring
3. Correct IAM permissions
4. Lambda and APIGateway in good working order

#### 1. Make sure you have the right lambda response

The return format of the return value of the lambda is crutial for the creation of the `aws_appautoscaling_target`.
It needs to be **EXACTLY** :

```py
    returningJson = {
      "actualCapacity": float(actualCapacity),
      "desiredCapacity": float(desiredCapacity),
      "dimensionName": resourceName,
      "resourceName": resourceName,
      "scalableTargetDimensionId": resourceName,
      "scalingStatus": scalingStatus,
      "version": "MyVersion"
    }
    
    try:
        returningJson['failureReason'] = failureReason
    except:
        pass
```

> (that's the way it's defined in the sample)...
> In my implementation I had played around with it (before everything was deployed and done) thinking I could get more data out of the `GET` call, for metrics and monitoring...
> Turns out that in the end when everything else was done, all I had to do was to restore the return function and it all connected successfully.

#### 2. API Gateway settings and wiring

This part caused me trouble. I think that it to be done exactly right for the *Auto Scaling* API to connect and find the target so it can register it (that's what the resource you're trying to create does)
[This API definition](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-application-auto-scaling-kinesis/blob/master/cloudformation/custom-application-autoscaling-kinesis.yaml#L153,L195) is a valid `openapi.yaml` definition.
I suggest putting that in a file like this one:

### `openapi.yaml.template`

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: "${NAME}"
paths:
  '/scalableTargetDimensions/{scalableTargetDimensionId}':
    get:
      tags:
        - ScalableTargets
      x-tags:
        - tag: ScalableTargets
      security:
        - sigv4: []
      x-amazon-apigateway-any-method:
        produces:
          - application/json
        consumes:
          - application/json
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        httpMethod: POST
        type: aws_proxy
        uri: ${INTEGRATION_URI}
        responses: {}
    patch:
      tags:
        - ScalableTargets
      x-tags:
        - tag: ScalableTargets
      security:
        - sigv4: []
      x-amazon-apigateway-any-method:
        security:
          - sigv4: []
        produces:
          - application/json
        consumes:
          - application/json
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        httpMethod: POST
        type: aws_proxy
        uri: ${INTEGRATION_URI}
        responses: {}
securityDefinitions:
  sigv4:
    type: apiKey
    name: Authorization
    in: header
    x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: awsSigv4
```

And you can then use it in this way:

```
# API Gateway
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "gateway" {
  name = var.rest_api_name
  body = templatefile("${path.module}/openapi.yaml.template",
    {
      NAME            = var.rest_api_name,
      INTEGRATION_URI = var.integration_uri
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "gateway" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_rest_api.gateway,
  ]

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.gateway.id
  stage_name  = var.stage_name
}
```

#### 3. Correct IAM permissions

The permissions defined in the `cloudformation` templates and those that you can create with `terraform` are not an *exact* match and seem to need some tweeking for the integration to work... (I suspect this has to do with some AWS magic, but I find it overall relatively easy to transfer to terraform)
So here are the `role` and `policies` I ended up creating:

```
# Lambda
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  # ...
  role = aws_iam_role.kinesis_autoscaler_lambda_role.arn
  # ...
}
resource "aws_iam_role" "kinesis_autoscaler_lambda_role" {
  name               = "${var.env}-kinesis-scaler-lambda-role"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "kinesis_api" {
  statement_id  = "AllowKinesisAPIInvoke"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambda.function_name
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${aws_api_gateway_deployment.gateway.execution_arn}/GET/scalableTargetDimensions/{scalableTargetDimensionId}"
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "kinesis_api_patch" {
  statement_id  = "AllowKinesisAPIPatchInvoke"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambda.function_name
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${aws_api_gateway_deployment.gateway.execution_arn}/PATCH/scalableTargetDimensions/{scalableTargetDimensionId}"
}

# Permissions
resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda_access_stream" {
  name = "${var.stream_name}-access-stream-policy"
                                      
  policy = <<POLICY                 
{                           
  "Version": "2012-10-17",                                          
  "Statement": [                                              
    {                                               
      "Sid": "KinesisConsumerAccess",     
      "Effect": "Allow",                                  
      "Action": [                                     
        "kinesis:DescribeStreamConsumer"               
      ],                                               
      "Resource": "${aws_kinesis_stream.stream.arn}/consumer/*:*"
    },                                        
    {                                                                                                                  
      "Sid": "KinesisStreamAccess",      
      "Effect": "Allow",                                                  
      "Action": [                                             
        "kinesis:DescribeLimits",                               
        "kinesis:DescribeStream",                                                                                     
        "kinesis:DescribeStreamConsumer",               
        "kinesis:DescribeStreamSummary",                                                                               
        "kinesis:UpdateShardCount"                      
      ],                                                      
      "Resource": "${aws_kinesis_stream.stream.arn}" 
    },                               
    {                                                              
      "Sid": "SSMParameterStoreGet",                                                                                
      "Effect": "Allow",                                  
      "Action": [    
        "ssm:GetParameter"           
      ],                                           
      "Resource": [                      
        "${aws_ssm_parameter.number_of_shards.arn}",    
      ]                                                           
    },                                             
    {                                                     
      "Sid": "SSMParameterStorePut",                      
      "Effect": "Allow",                                                                                               
      "Action": [                            
        "ssm:PutParameter"                                    
      ],                                
      "Resource": [                                                         
        "${aws_ssm_parameter.number_of_shards.arn}"
      ]                          
    }                                  
  ]                                 
}                                    
POLICY                                
}                  
# I ended up splitting the policies for `module` reasons...                              
resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "attach_lambda_stream_access" {
  name = "${aws_iam_role.kinesis_autoscaler_lambda_role.name}_attach_lambda_stream_access"
  roles = [                                         
    aws_iam_role.kinesis_autoscaler_lambda_role.name                  
  ]                                                       
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.lambda_access_stream.arn
}
```

This last one is an important one. It's the result of the final tweekings I have done to make the lambda work.

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda_access_scaling" {
  name = "${var.stream_name}-lambda-access-scaling-policy"

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "FindScalingPolicyARNAndAlarms",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalingPolicies",
        "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "UpdateAlarms",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm",
        "cloudwatch:DeleteAlarms"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.alarm_out.arn}",
        "${aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.alarm_in.arn}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "attach_scaling_access" {
  name = "${aws_iam_role.kinesis_autoscaler_lambda_role.name}_attach_scaling_access"
  roles = [
    aws_iam_role.kinesis_autoscaler_lambda_role.name
  ]
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.lambda_access_scaling.arn
}
```

Also, you want to have the right permissions for the `custom_appautoscaling`...

```
# For reference:  
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "kinesis_stream" {
  min_capacity       = var.min_number_of_shard
  max_capacity       = var.max_number_of_shard
  resource_id        = "${aws_api_gateway_deployment.gateway.invoke_url}/scalableTargetDimensions/${var.stream_name}"           
  role_arn           = aws_iam_role.custom_appautoscaling_service_role.arn
  scalable_dimension = "custom-resource:ResourceType:Property"
  service_namespace  = "custom-resource"
                                                                   
  depends_on = [                                        
    aws_iam_policy_attachment.attach_base_policy,
  ]                                                     
                 
  lifecycle {                                        
    ignore_changes = [
      # This is because the "assume_role_policy" becomes the actual
      # Role "AWSServiceRoleForApplicationAutoScaling_CustomResource"                                               
      # at runtime and is always attemted to be recreated 
      role_arn,
    ]              
  }
}                         
          
# Actual policies:
 
resource "aws_iam_role" "custom_appautoscaling_service_role" {
  name               = "${var.stream_name}-assume-custom-resource"
  assume_role_policy = <<-EOF                   
  {        
    "Version": "2012-10-17",                            
    "Statement": [
      {                                      
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Principal": {
          "Service": "custom-resource.application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com"
        },                                       
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": ""  
      }
    ]                     
  }             
  EOF
}                           
                        
resource "aws_iam_policy" "base_policy" {
  name = "${var.stream_name}_base_policy"
                                 
  policy = <<POLICY
{                  
  "Version": "2012-10-17",                             
  "Statement": [                                     
    {  
      "Sid": "DescribeAlarms",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },                                                             
    {                                                   
      "Sid": "InvokeApiGateway",
      "Effect": "Allow",                                
      "Action": [
        "execute-api:Invoke*"                        
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_api_gateway_deployment.gateway.execution_arn}/scalableTargetDimensions/${var.stream_name}"
      ]                                                   
    }
  ]                
}
POLICY                    
}               
     
resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "attach_base_policy" {
  name = "${var.stream_name}_attach_base_policy"
  roles = [      
    aws_iam_role.custom_appautoscaling_service_role.name  
  ]                                
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.base_policy.arn
}                    
      
resource "aws_iam_policy" "alarms_modification" {
  name = "${var.stream_name}_alarms_modification"
                        
  policy = <<POLICY
{                                   
  "Version": "2012-10-17",       
  "Statement": [
    {              
      "Sid": "UpdateAlarms",                           
      "Effect": "Allow",                             
      "Action": [
        "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm",
        "cloudwatch:DeleteAlarms"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.alarm_out.arn}",
        "${aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.alarm_in.arn}"
      ]                                                       
    }                                                   
  ]        
}                       
POLICY
}                                                      
 
resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "attach_alarms_modification" {                        
  name = "${var.stream_name}_attach_alarms_modification"
  roles = [                                            
    aws_iam_role.custom_appautoscaling_service_role.name
  ]
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.alarms_modification.arn
}
```

#### 4. Lambda and APIGateway in good working order

Finally, if after all of this still doesn't work, you might want to troubleshoot your lambda and APIGateway...
I ended up using the `apigateway-aws-proxy` *Event Template* in the lambda console. Editing a bit the fields so that it looks like this:

```json
{
  "body": {
    "desiredCapacity": "1"
  },
  "resource": "/{proxy+}",
  "path": "/scalableTargetDimensions/my-custom-stream",
  "httpMethod": "PATCH",
...
  "requestContext" {
    ...
    "path": "/<STAGE_NAME_SEE_API_GATEWAY_DEPLOYMENT_RESOURCE>/scalableTargetDimensions/my-custom-stream",
    "resourcePath": "/{proxy+}",
    "httpMethod": "PATCH",
}
```

> Also for this part, I created one that had a `base64encoded` body (because it's the way it's passed by the APIGateway I guess?)...
> Anyway I ended up tweeking the lambda a bit so it accept both, this way it's possible to know if the lambad actually works properly.

```json
{
  "body": "eyJkZXNpcmVkQ2FwYWNpdHkiOiIyIn0=",
  "resource": "/{proxy+}",
  "path": "/scalableTargetDimensions/my-custom-stream",
  "httpMethod": "PATCH",
  "isBase64Encoded": true,
...
```

With this, you should be able to troubleshoot the lambda, making sure all permission is properly granted.
To troubleshoot the APIGateway, you could always use [postman](https://www.postman.com/). It handles nicely the authentication to AWS so if you have credentials with adequate access to the `APIGateway` resource you've created, you should be able to do some `GET` and `PATCH` to manually trigger the `APIGateway` and test this part of the integration.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for taking the effort! I had managed to overcome the issue by using CloudFormation instead of Terraform, and I think the issue I was having was because of the IAM Permissions that you mention in your answer. I am going to try your suggestions. However, for your sheer effort and answer quality, I have put a bounty on this question and I will give it to you when the timeout expires! Good work!